# Scrapy XMLFeedSpider is very slow

Tags: scrapy

I have a very slow performing scraper. I know the bottle neck is not the pipeline (i.e. bi_pipeline) because other scrapers that don't use `XMLFeedSpider` are very fast. Here is my code:

```
class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'my.pipelines.bi_pipeline': 400
        }
    }

    start_urls=["http://localhost/my.xml"]

    iterator = 'iternodes'  # This is actually unnecessary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'DEALER'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
   
        my_item = Dealer()

        my_item['title'] = node.xpath('TITLE/text()').get()

        # send to pipeline to get stored in database
        yield my_item
        
        # get the sales for each dealer
        yield Request("https://some.domain.com/od/dealers.json?id=" + node.xpath('ID/text()').get(), callback=self.each_sale)
```

I don't know why but this is very slow. Like 35 items per minute. Where should I look to optimize?

Comment: What happens if you simply visit the pages? Maybe the server simply is slow or is rate-limiting you?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was an update script being called on a Trigger in the database. It was a clean up script and the target I was running it on needed a lot of cleaning.